# How to set file type when using TextIO.write to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

I wrote a DataFlow pipeline that outputs a single small csv file on Google Cloud Storage. The file type of that file is `text/plain` but i want it to be `application/csv`.

this is the code i use

```
TextIO.write()
.to("gs://bucket/path/to/filename").withoutSharding()
.withSuffix(".csv")
.withDelimiter(new char[]{'\r','\n'})
```

How do i specify the file type so that the file type will be `application/csv` after the pipeline completes?

Comment: Please edit the question to show how are you creating the file in Cloud Storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TextIO always write content type **text/plain**. This is configured here. https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextSink.java#L95

One option for you might be to update the content type of objects already written to GCS. This can be done using the *gsutil* tool after you finish your Dataflow pipeline that writes files. See here for more information.
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/setmeta